# Decimal without decimal places and comma formatted values

Tags: c#, asp.net

How this i can solve,

In database I have field for example Test decimal(18,2), and in text box user entered 656,347.
In aspx i try

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Test", "{0:n0}") %>' />
```

and get this: Error while setting property 'Test': '656,347 is not a valid value for Decimal.'.
When i try F0 everything works, but i dont have comma separator. How can I do this.
My UICulture and Culture is en-US, and I can't change database field.